# Why are multi-methods not working as functions for Reagent/Re-frame?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

In a small app I'm building that uses Reagent and Re-frame I'm using multi-methods to dispatch which page should be shown based on a value in the app state:

```
(defmulti pages :name)

(defn main-panel []
  (let [current-route (re-frame/subscribe [:current-route])]
    (fn []
      ;...
      (pages @current-route))))
```

and then I have methods such as:

```
(defmethod layout/pages :register [_] [register-page])
```

where the `register-page` function would generate the actual view:

```
(defn register-page []
  (let [registration-form (re-frame/subscribe [:registration-form])]
    (fn []
      [:div
       [:h1 "Register"]
       ;...
       ])))
```

I tried [changing my app so that the methods generated the pages directly](https://github.com/carouselapps/ninjatools/commit/96eeff36757ef9569e3bec81bf5edcc336daedcb), as in:

```
(defmethod layout/pages :register [_]
  (let [registration-form (re-frame/subscribe [:registration-form])]
    (fn []
      [:div
       [:h1 "Register"]
       ;...
       ])))
```

and that caused no page to ever be rendered. In my main panel I [changed the call to `pages` to square brackets](https://github.com/carouselapps/ninjatools/commit/f9ee01045898e26b9ad56727c71c3d6bf7c6eaf4) so that Reagent would have visibility into it:

```
(defn main-panel []
  (let [current-route (re-frame/subscribe [:current-route])]
    (fn []
      ;...
      [pages @current-route])))
```

and that caused the first visited page to work, but after that, clicking on links (which causes current-route to change) has no effect.

All the namespaces defining the individual methods are required in the file that is loaded first, that contains the init function, and the fact that I can pick any single page and have it displayed proves the code is loading (then, switching to another page doesn't work):

https://github.com/carouselapps/ninjatools/blob/master/src/cljs/ninjatools/core.cljs#L8-L12

In an effort to debug what's going on, I defined two routes, `:about` and `:about2`, one as a function and one as a method:

```
(defn about-page []
  (fn []
    [:div "This is the About Page."]))

(defmethod layout/pages :about [_]
  [about-page])

(defmethod layout/pages :about2 [_]
  (fn []
    [:div "This is the About 2 Page."]))
```

and made the layout print the result of calling `pages` (had to use the explicit call instead of the square brackets of course). The wrapped function, the one that works, returns:

```
[#object[ninjatools$pages$about_page "function ninjatools$pages$about_page(){
return (function (){
return new cljs.core.PersistentVector(null, 2, 5, cljs.core.PersistentVector.EMPTY_NODE, [new cljs.core.Keyword(null,"div","div",1057191632),"This is the About Page."], null);
});
}"]]
```

while the method returns:

```
#object[Function "function (){
return new cljs.core.PersistentVector(null, 2, 5, cljs.core.PersistentVector.EMPTY_NODE, [new cljs.core.Keyword(null,"div","div",1057191632),"This is the About 2 Page."], null);
}"]
```

If I change the method to be:

```
(defmethod layout/pages :about2 [_]
  [(fn []
     [:div "This is the About 2 Page."])])
```

that is, returning the function in a vector, then, it starts to work. And if I make the reverse change to the wrapped function, it starts to fail in the same manner as the method:

```
(defn about-page []
  (fn []
    [:div "This is the About Page."]))

(defmethod layout/pages :about [_]
  about-page)
```

Makes a bit of sense as Reagent's syntax is `[function]` but it was supposed to call the function automatically.

I also started outputting `@current-route` to the browser, as in:

```
[:main.container
 [alerts/view]
 [pages @current-route]
 [:div (pr-str @current-route)]]
```

and I verified `@current-route` is being modified correctly and the output updated, just not `[pages @current-route]`.

The full source code for my app can be found here: https://github.com/carouselapps/ninjatools/tree/multi-methods

**[Update: corrected the arity of the methods following Michał Marczyk's answer.](https://github.com/carouselapps/ninjatools/commit/971de441b46e407857625d5c8f0b90fd78a54dd0)**

Comment: Are you requiring the namespaces where you use `defmethod` in some root namespace? Because if you don't require those namespaces explicitly, your methods simply don't get added to the multimethod.

Comment: @skrat yes. I'll edit the question to note that.

Comment: To debug this I would 1. Add a default method and 2. print out what the multimethod is returning (probably nil).

Comment: @PeakCode I do have a default method: https://github.com/carouselapps/ninjatools/blob/multi-methods/src/cljs/ninjatools/layout.cljs#L14 and if that was being rendered I would get a blank main content. Instead, the page just doesn't refresh.

Comment: @PeakCode when the method is in square brackets, I'm not calling it myself, so, printing its output is hard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have all the details, but apparently, when I was rendering pages like this:

```
[:main.container
 [alerts/view]
 [pages @current-route]]
```

Reagent was failing to notice that `pages` depended on the value of `@current-route`. The [Chrome React plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) helped me figure it out. I tried using a ratom instead of a subscription and that seemed to work fine. Thankfully, [telling Reagent/React the key to an element is easy enough](https://github.com/carouselapps/ninjatools/commit/01a4bea156655f0aa756a0960135e9ca99ac0922):

```
[:main.container
 [alerts/view]
 ^{:key @current-route} [pages @current-route]]
```

That works just fine.

Comment: reagent/React will destroy and recreate the pages component each time the key changes. So this method will work,  but just be aware of how.

Comment: Just to be clear,   this statement:  `Reagent was failing to notice that pages depended on the value of @current-route`
is incorrect. Have a look at my answer for an explanation of what's happening.

Answer (score 15):

So, a component like this: `[pages @some-ratom]`
will rerender when `pages` changes or `@some-ratom` changes.

From reagent's point of view, `pages` hasn't changed since last time, it is still the same multi-method it was before.  But `@some-ratom` might change, so that could trigger a rerender.

**But** when this rerender happens it will be done using a cached version of `pages`.  After all, it does not appear to reagent that `pages` has changed.  It is still the same multimethod it was before.

The cached version of `pages` will, of course, be the first version of `pages` which was rendered - the first version of the mutlimethod and **not** the new version we expect to see used.

Reagent does this caching because it must handle Form-2 functions.  It has to keep the returned render function.

Bottom line:  because of the caching, multimethods won't work very well, unless you find a way to completely blow up the component and start again, which is what the currently-top-voted approach does:
   `^{:key @current-route} [pages @current-route]`
Of course, blowing up the component and starting again might have its own unwelcome implications (depending on what local state is held in that component).

Vaguely Related Background:
https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/wiki/Creating-Reagent-Components#appendix-a---lifting-the-lid-slightly
https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/wiki/When-do-components-update%3F

Comment: what's an elegant alternative to multi-methods that doesn't have unwelcome implications?

Answer (score 2):

The first problem that jumps out at me is that your methods take no arguments:

```
(defmethod layout/pages :register [] [register-page])
                                  ^ arglist
```

Here you have an empty arglist, but presumably you'll be calling this multimethod with one or two arguments (since its dispatch function is a keyword and keywords can be called with one or two arguments).

If you want to call this multimethod with a single argument and just ignore it inside the body of the `:register` method, change the above to

```
(defmethod layout/pages :register [_] [register-page])
                                   ^ argument to be ignored
```

---

Also, I expect you'll probably want to call `pages` yourself like you previously did (that is, revert the change to square brackets that you mentioned in the question).

---

This may or may not fix the app – there may be other problems – but it should get you started. (The multimethod will definitely not work with those empty arglists if you pass in any arguments.)

Comment: Good point about the argument list. I think ClojureScript just doesn't check the arity of functions and methods. I made this change but the app still behaves the same way: https://github.com/carouselapps/ninjatools/commit/971de441b46e407857625d5c8f0b90fd78a54dd0

Answer (score 1):

How about if you instead have a wrapper `pages-component` function which is a regular function that can be cached by reagent.  It would look like this:

```
(defn pages-component [state]
  (layout/pages @state))
```